# Can't make a method static in ReSharper because menus are greyed out

Tags: class, function, resharper

I'm trying to follow some steps to move methods from one class to another class with *ReSharper 7.1.1*. One of the steps to do this involves making the method static, however, the context menu entry `Make Method Static...` seems to be disabled and greyed out. The strange thing is it wasn't greyed out before on the same function, but after I discarded my changes to do it again, it seems to be greyed out now.

I've tried highlighting the function name and the whole function itself to try to make the menu entry active, but still no luck. How can I enable the `Make Method Static...` menu again?

Comment: You say you discarded your changes and started again - is it possible it thinks your first change is still applied, and therefore the method is already static?

Comment: If that is the case, then how do I go about clearing its memory so that it would see it as a new method to perform the operation on? When I discarded it, I just reverted to my old files before the changes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please check that your method is not virtual and is not used to implement an interface. Otherwise, please provide a code sample.

Comment: You're right, it is implementing an interface. When I commented the function prototype out of the interface the menu entry became enabled again. I must have done that when I was playing around with it the first time. So I guess the advice is to comment out the prototypes in the interface to move the methods, and then re-enable them afterwards?

Comment: @Xolstice Yes, I think that would be the easiest way.